# I am having issues parsing JSON does anyone know why? (Further context provided)

Tags: javascript, json, http, ecmascript-6, get

I am trying to parse this JSON data from the urban dictionary API:

```
{
   "tags":[
      "poop",
      "shit",
      "sex",
      "ass",
      "anal",
      "cob",
      "penis",
      "indiana",
      "dog",
      "food"
   ],
   "result_type":"exact",
   "list":[
      {
         "definition":"Something I shitted the other day that I never ate.",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/1074446",
         "thumbs_up":1065,
         "author":"fat bastard",
         "word":"corn",
         "defid":1074446,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2005-02-20T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"::Looks in toilet::\r\nWhat!?... I never ate any corn!",
         "thumbs_down":570
      },
      {
         "definition":"originated in Jersey.\n\n1. It is equivalent to a sardonic cool.\n\n2. Cool, no one gives a shit.",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/5175475",
         "thumbs_up":342,
         "author":"MikeK3",
         "word":"corn",
         "defid":5175475,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2010-08-23T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"Damian: Yo, I just scored forty points in a rec game with the nigs. Then had a volleyball game and had forty kills.\n\nOther: Corn\n\nDamian: ...",
         "thumbs_down":251
      },
      {
         "definition":"A ground grown grain, that is full of starch... NOT a VEGETABLE! And, NOT a starch.\n\nIn history corused to be part of a weed called \"Teosinte\". It was very small, and barely eatable. This was usually grown in cetural america.\n\nThis later evolved in the what they called \"Maize\", what we now call early maize. It would be large enough to eat, and was used in replacement of the vegetable.\n\nNow we know corn as the modern maize. The normal crop rage from 6-12 inches long, and 2-5 inches wide. The corn is on waht we call a cob, and the corn grows around it taking the nutrience from the cob. I has become a normal dish in our would today.",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/4248083",
         "thumbs_up":202,
         "author":"Bear///Claw",
         "word":"Corn",
         "defid":4248083,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2009-09-20T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"Person 1: What vegetable do you want for dinner?\n\nPerson 2: Let us have a grain instead, we can have corn! I need to have some starch anyways.\n\nPerson 1: Would you like to eat the corn off of the cob, or cut if off first?\n\nPerson 2: All the same to me.",
         "thumbs_down":134
      },
      {
         "definition":"1 - Yellow food on cob.\r\n2 - Digestion timing device.  Simply see how much time passes from corn digestion to seeing it in the toilet.\r\n3 - Elvis's last word.",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/183886",
         "thumbs_up":224,
         "author":"Kuzin Rob",
         "word":"corn",
         "defid":183886,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2003-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"1 - I will have the 32 oz. Porterhouse, rare, with mashed potatoes and corn.\r\n2 - A healthy person's digestive system will pass corn in 12 to 24 hours.\r\n\"Look daddy!  There's a smiley face on that poopie!\"\r\n\"Yes, son.  It's made of corn.\"\r\n3 - \"WTF?!  CORN?!?\"  *GASP* *DEATH*",
         "thumbs_down":176
      },
      {
         "definition":"An appropriate replacement for inappropriate swear words.",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/5958827",
         "thumbs_up":105,
         "author":"Exploding Ovens",
         "word":"corn",
         "defid":5958827,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2011-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"What the corn is up with all this corning summer homework...\" \"Corn it, dude.",
         "thumbs_down":61
      },
      {
         "definition":"north eastern slang word for good marajuana usualy used in the getto or on the phone for a paraoid dealer of drugs",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/2438466",
         "thumbs_up":245,
         "author":"Zachary Finch",
         "word":"corn",
         "defid":2438466,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2007-05-27T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"(phone) yo man i need that hook up on corn this week ",
         "thumbs_down":201
      },
      {
         "definition":"Originating from the fine campus of Cornell University comes this unique, rarely used term. Saying that a girl is \"Corn\" means, she is so hot, so beautiful, so utterly drop-dead gorgeous, that you would happily eat the corn out of her shit. Can be used as a great pick-up line or friendly compliment",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/793026",
         "thumbs_up":408,
         "author":"Long Island",
         "word":"Corn",
         "defid":793026,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2004-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"\"Damn bitch, you are Corn!\"\r\nor\r\n\"Baby, you're more Corn than Green Giant\"",
         "thumbs_down":378
      },
      {
         "definition":"1. A word used as a synonym or euphamisim for sensual, promiscuous, or sexy.\n\n2. Slang derived from the horror film Troll 2\n\n3. See also: Corn Star, Corn Dog, Corny",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/5535118",
         "thumbs_up":92,
         "author":"cornstar69",
         "word":"Corn",
         "defid":5535118,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2011-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"*hot guy walks in room*\r\nAlex: Dayuuummm\r\nAnnalis: That guy is Corn!\r\nAlex: I wanna Corn him!\r\nAnnalis: What a Corn Star!",
         "thumbs_down":66
      },
      {
         "definition":"another word for a butthole",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/5321648",
         "thumbs_up":61,
         "author":"cheeboiiwasabi",
         "word":"corn",
         "defid":5321648,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2010-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"''hey is it true,nunnas licked that girl's corn?",
         "thumbs_down":40
      },
      {
         "definition":"The thing that makes up about 99.99% of Iowa's economy. If there's no corn, Iowa will die.",
         "permalink":"http://corn.urbanup.com/6693555",
         "thumbs_up":32,
         "author":"milez97",
         "word":"Corn",
         "defid":6693555,
         "current_vote":"",
         "written_on":"2012-07-25T00:00:00.000Z",
         "example":"\"This drought is going to kill us all here in Iowa. Even worse, it's killing the corn.\"",
         "thumbs_down":22
      }
   ],
   "sounds":[

   ]
}
```

This is the javascript code to fetch it:

```
function getUrbanWord(urbanWord) {
    let url = `http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=${urbanWord}`;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();

    request.onload = function() {


        var list = urbanResponse.list;
        for (index in list) {
            console.log(`
         ${list.definition}
         ${list.permalink}
         ${list.thumbs_up}
         ${list.author}
         ${list.word}
         ${list.defid}
         ${list.current_vote}
         ${list.written_on}
         ${list.example}
         ${list.thumbs_down}

   `);
        }
    }

}
```

When I console.log the data i recieve an "undefined" I am just wondering if anyone knows what is going on and how I can handle it.
I am jsut trying to print it so I can use it later on for context I am using the REPL.IT editor if you think that has anything to do with this error please inform me thank you Carlos

Comment: I think you forgot to make `urbanResponse` a parameter to your "onload" callback.

Comment: `for (index in list)`  your loop is `index`, but then you do -> `${list.definition}` instead of `${list[index].definition}`, also I would use `for (index of list)` instead, then you could do `${index.definition}`

Comment: I will leave a link to the GitHub pages of the small hobby project in a bit thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`for (index in list)`, as it sounds, loops over each *index* of the list. `list` is an array, not an object, so you can't access it via `list.definition`.

Either use `[index]` notation to indicate that you want to access the `index`th element of the `list` array:

```
for (index in list) {
  console.log(`
    ${list[index].definition}
    // ...
```

or, even better, loop over the array directly with `forEach`:

```
list.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(`
    ${item.definition}
    ${item.permalink}
    // ...
```

You also need to be able to access the response in the first place; `urbanResponse` is not defined in your code above.

```
request.onload = function(responseText) {
  const urbanResponse = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes.

Fix code as following:

```js
function getUrbanWord(urbanWord) {
    let url = `//api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=${urbanWord}`;
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.addEventListener( "load", function() {

        for (let list of request.response.list) {
            console.log(`
         ${list.definition}
         ${list.permalink}
         ${list.thumbs_up}
         ${list.author}
         ${list.word}
         ${list.defid}
         ${list.current_vote}
         ${list.written_on}
         ${list.example}
         ${list.thumbs_down}

   `);
        }
    } );

    request.send();
}
getUrbanWord( "apple" );
```

First, there is no `urbanResponse` in onload listener.

Second, `list` is an array and not an individual item in for-loop block.

Answer (score 1):

the result pof the request is under `urbanResponse.target.response.list` and not `urbanResponse.list` , and you can use a regular `for` loop to iterate through that list : ( and you forget the parameter `urbanResponse` in the function )

```js
function getUrbanWord(urbanWord) {
  let url = `https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=${urbanWord}`;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();

  request.onload = function(urbanResponse) {

    var list = urbanResponse.target.response.list;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(`
         ${list[i].definition}
         ${list[i].permalink}
         ${list[i].thumbs_up}
         ${list[i].author}
         ${list[i].word}
         ${list[i].defid}
         ${list[i].current_vote}
         ${list[i].written_on}
         ${list[i].example}
         ${list[i].thumbs_down}

   `);
    }
  }

}

getUrbanWord('hello')
```

Comment: Thank you it was a simple fix i just had a brain fart thank you!